# Cascading Style Sheet property preventing a href from working

Tags: html, css

I have downloaded from codepen this animated login [here](https://codepen.io/Lewitje/pen/BNNJjo)

I am simply trying to add an `a href` link within the `html` container div where folks can reset their password.

[image]

The strange thing is, I can not get this or any link of any sorts to work. (all links irrespective of destination are not live).

I think that there may be a `CSS` property preventing all href from working.

Any reason for this?

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/loginstyle.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form class="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">           
            <input type="text" name="username" required placeholder="Enter Username">
            <input type="password" name="password" required placeholder="Enter Password">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" id="login-button">Login</button>
        </form>

        <!-- is this link being prevented from working by bg-bubbles class or its css -->

         <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">LINK</a>
    </div>

    <!-- bg-bubbles class seems to prevent all a href's from working -->

    <ul class="bg-bubbles">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**loginstyle.css**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
  src: local('Source Sans Pro ExtraLight'), local('SourceSansPro-ExtraLight'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v11/6xKydSBYKcSV-LCoeQqfX1RYOo3i94_wlxdr.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Source Sans Pro Light'), local('SourceSansPro-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v11/6xKydSBYKcSV-LCoeQqfX1RYOo3ik4zwlxdr.ttf) format('truetype');
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* WebKit browsers */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body :-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body ::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body :-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.wrapper {
  background: #50a3a2;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper.form-success .container h1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(85px);
          transform: translateY(85px);
}
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 80px 0;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-put;
  font-weight: 200;
}
form {
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
form input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
  font-weight: 300;
}
form input:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
form input:focus {
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  color: #53e3a6;
}
form button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #53e3a6;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}
form button:hover {
  background-color: #f5f7f9;
}


.bg-bubbles {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}


.bg-bubbles li {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  bottom: -160px;
  -webkit-animation: square 25s infinite;
  animation: square 25s infinite;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}


.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(1) {
  left: 10%;
}

.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(2) {
  left: 20%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
          animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 17s;
          animation-duration: 17s;
}


.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(3) {
  left: 25%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
          animation-delay: 4s;
}


.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(4) {
  left: 40%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 22s;
          animation-duration: 22s;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}


.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(5) {
  left: 70%;
}

.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(6) {
  left: 80%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
          animation-delay: 3s;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(7) {
  left: 32%;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7s;
          animation-delay: 7s;
}


.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(8) {
  left: 55%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
          animation-delay: 15s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 40s;
          animation-duration: 40s;
}


.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(9) {
  left: 25%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
          animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 40s;
          animation-duration: 40s;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}


.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(10) {
  left: 90%;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 11s;
          animation-delay: 11s;
}





@-webkit-keyframes square {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
            transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
  }
}
@keyframes square {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
            transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a z-index to the a-tag? By default this has a value of one, and every element placed after this will overlap and this results in the click-event not being triggering.

Comment: I haven't how would that look syntax wise,

Comment: Sorry Weng Tee, had a sudden emergency yesterday that needed my attention. Luckily someone else helped you out. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `z-index:2;` to the `a` tag along with `position: relative;` [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rbLrKp) is the updated codepen.

I've created a class

```
.forgot-password{
z-index:2;
position:relative;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

and added it to anchor tag.